# Comparing bigdecimal output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal

A SQL query is outputting a bigdecimal output that I expect to be `144.50`, and the actual value is coming as `#<BigDecimal:7fbe367ed118,'0.1445E3',18(18)>`

I tried the following to compare the two:

```
assert_equal BigDecimal('144.50'), actual_value
```

but this fails with:

```
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<BigDecimal:7fbe367ed938,'0.1445E3',18(18)>
+#<BigDecimal:7fbe367ed118,'0.1445E3',18(18)>
```

Looks like the failure is because of the actual and expected values being different objects.

Is this the right way to compare big decimal objects in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assertion is saying "does this object equal this other object".  It appears you want to compare values.

You can do that like so:

```
[4] pry(main)> BigDecimal('144.50') == 144.50                                             
=> true
```

That would make your test look something like:

```
assert_equal 144.50, actual_value
```

where actual_value is coming from the database.

Comment: Thanks. That does work. I got sidetracked by a different issue when the output is an array of big decimals.

Comment: `assert_equal(exp, act)` calls `assert(exp == act)` and `BigDecimal('144.50') == BigDecimal('144.50') #=> true`

Comment: interesting, you're right @Stefan .  I don't use TestUnit that much, is it also testing object_id equality?  I don't see anything else different in his example.